# "Method $ is undefined" in a JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, junit4

My test code uses Junit4 -

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import junitparams.Parameters;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FootballTeamTest {

    @Test
    @Parameters(method ="nbOfGamesWon")
    public void constructorShouldSetGamesWon(int nbOfGamesWon) {
        FootballTeam team = new FootballTeam(nbOfGamesWon);
        assertEquals(nbOfGamesWon, team.getGamesWon());
    }

    public Object[] nbOfGamesWon(){
        return $(0,1,2);
    }

}
```

Error in line `return $(0,1,2);` - `The method $(int, int, int) is undefined for the type FootballTeamTest`

My book uses this kind of code without problems. Why does this error occur for me and how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you don't have a method named `$` with three parameters of type `int`. Define such a method and you'll be able to invoke it.

```
public Object[] $(int a, int b, int c) {
    return new Object[0]; // or whatever initialization logic you need
}
```

[Note that the JLS states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-JavaLetter)

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters
>   A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical
>   reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or
>   \u0024). **The $ sign should be used only in mechanically generated
>   source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy
>   systems.**

So maybe your book has some of that. Otherwise, don't use `$` as an identifier name.

[This junitparams library](https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams) provides a method named `$`. You might be missing it.

```
import static junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.$;
```

Comment: Oh yes. Duh ! I'll add the edit to your code. `import static junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.$;`

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev That doesn't seem like a junit library class. Are you sure it's not a custom class?

Comment: I started reading my book after a long time. Went back and saw the import I mentioned. I only use `junit.jar version 4` and `org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0`. I don't use any custom code developed by the author.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev [Seems like another library.](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/pl.pragmatists/JUnitParams/0.3.4/junitparams/JUnitParamsRunner.java). Also, see [here](https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams).

Comment: Yes, I checked another folder called Referenced libraries. It uses `JUnitParams-1.0.2.jar`. My bad. I did all this a while ago.